# Create constrained initializer without using the type in the signature

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
protocol SimpleInit {
    init()
}

class Person {}

class Lizard<T: Person> {
    let person: T

    init(person: T) {
        self.person = person
    }

    // error: 'where' clause cannot be attached to a non-generic declaration
    init() where T: SimpleInit { 
        self.person = T.init()
    }
}
```

Is it possible that I have a subclass of `Person` which conforms to `SimpleInit`, and later on constructs a `Lizard` without passing an instance of `Person` to the constructor? `Lizard` should be able to create a `Person` if the type of `Person` conforms to `SimpleInit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move your initializer into a conditional extension:

```
protocol SimpleInit {
    init()
}

class Person {
    required init() {}
}

class Lizard<T: Person> {
    let person: T

    required init(person: T) {
        self.person = person
    }

}

extension Lizard where T: SimpleInit {
    convenience init()  { 
        self.init(person: T.init())
    }
}
```